# Is there an way to Loop in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a monthly Forecasting process in SQL.  I've created a query for Jan and wanted to see if it's possible to loop through each additional month and store the results in a Temporary table.

Logically, I would like to set @DMonth variable to 1, run the query, store/append the results into a temp table, loop...

set @DMonth variable to 2, run the query, store/append the results into a temp table, loop...

etc.. setting @DMonth sequentially until it reaches 12 and then exit the loop.

Example variable in query:

```
Declare @DMonth int;
set @DMonth = 1
```

I believe I need to set the Loop around the Setting to of the @DMonth variable.

Comment: It's rare to actually need a loop in SQL. Share your full query.

Comment: @dfundako Well, one could see a recursive CTE as a kind of conditional loop.  For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55947847/4003419)

Comment: "SQL" is best suited for set based processing.  That said "SQL Script" can loop; if you can avoid the loops which use cursors or recursive CTE's you will likely have a less costly query.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what do you really want to do inside your loop, but here is how to loop through and save month in a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(mon int);

Declare @StartDate DATETIME = '2016-09-01',
        @EndDate DATETIME = '2017-01-31'


-- Now you have 12 months and you can use below query to loop through each month starting from January 

WHILE (@StartDate <= @EndDate)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Month INT = Month(@StartDate) -- At the start of loop @Month is equal to 9 

    -- Save @Month to temp table in each repeat 
    INSERT INTO #temp (mon)
    SELECT @Month;

    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @StartDate); -- this line adds 1 value to @Month after first loop @Month will be 10 
END
```

If you want to start your loop from `@StartDate` (September 2016) and then end it in `@EndDate` (January 2017) the above query does the exact same process. But if you want to change your `@StartDate` to `2016-01-01` and `@EndDate` to `2016-12-31` then use below query:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(mon int);

Declare @StartDate DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, -8, '2016-09-01'); -- It will set @StartDate to '2016-01-01' 
Declare @EndDate DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, 11, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, '2017-01-31')); -- It will set @EndDate to '2016-12-31'

-- Now you have 12 months and you can use below query to loop through each month starting from January 

WHILE (@StartDate <= @EndDate)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Month INT = Month(@StartDate) -- At the begining @Month is equal to 1 

    -- Save @Month to temp table in each repeat 
    INSERT INTO #temp (mon)
    SELECT @Month;

    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @StartDate); -- this line adds 1 value to @Month after first loop @Month will be 2 
END
```

Comment: thanks, do you know how I could I adjust the variables in the loop?  Essentially, its changing dates.  where does the main query go after PRINT @counter; ?

Comment: Depends on what variant of SQL this is. @OP, are you using Microsoft SQL Server? If so, add the tag `sql-server` to your question, or maybe `sql-server-2012` for the actual release of MS SQL.

Comment: I put my parameters into a temp table #Variables that stores everything.

Comment: What do you mean by everything? You mean whole date? What do you want to do after looping through months?

Comment: I've simplified the query a bit.  At this point I just need to Set the @DMonth to 1, run the query, store the results in the temp table.   Then change Dmonth to 2, run the query, append the data into the temp table.  Then change Dmonth to 3, run the query, append the data into the temp table....  Repeat this process through 12.    the rest of variables will be automatically set with a join into a variable table I created with the dates

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course, you can loop in sql.The syntax is slightly different but similar and you can easily understand it if you know basic coding.However we can only use the while loop in sql.
The syntax is like shown Below.
 while loop. we basically use

While (n < X) = //Condition
BEGIN