# Get count of total employees under each manager (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I need to get, for each of the five people in this table, the total employees reporting to each one of them (either directly or indirectly).

```
CREATE TABLE employees
    ([employee] nvarchar(30), [manager] nvarchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO employees
    ([employee], [manager])
VALUES
    ('Robert', null),
    ('Julian', 'Robert'),
    ('Sophie', 'Robert'),
    ('Lucy', 'Julian'),
    ('John', 'Lucy')
;
```

The output I expect is:

| employee | subordinates |
| --- | --- |
| Robert | 4 |
| Julian | 2 |
| Lucy | 1 |
| Sophie | 0 |
| John | 0 |

I have searched everywhere how to do this type of recursion/hierarchical query, and it seems it is very common to approach this kind of exercise to get the employee hierarchy only (which I managed to do already), but not the total count of employees under each manager.

The best I could get was the following, but it only gets the count for the top manager, while I need it for all employees in the company in a single table (from an answer to this post: [SQL Query to get recursive count of employees under each manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690325/sql-query-to-get-recursive-count-of-employees-under-each-manager)).

```
WITH EmployeeCTE
     AS (SELECT e.employee, e.manager as topmanager
         FROM   employees e, employees m
         WHERE  e.manager = m.employee AND m.manager IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT e.employee, mgr.topmanager
         FROM   employees e, EmployeeCTE mgr
         WHERE  e.manager = mgr.employee)
SELECT topmanager, count(*)
FROM   EmployeeCTE AS u
GROUP BY topmanager;
```

Here is a Fiddle to this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/380ba/2

Comment: Your database schema is improperly normalized. You should have a separate table for managers, with a cross-reference table that maps employee IDs to manager IDs. Or if any employee can also be a manager, just a table that defines this relationship. "employee ID X manages employee ID Y". This makes joining and aggregating the relationship in question very straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with getting the zero subordinates for those without subordinates.

One way to get them is via a `LEFT JOIN` of all employees to the results of the recursive CTE.

> ```
> WITH CTE_Employees AS (
>   SELECT employee
>   FROM employees
>   GROUP BY employee
> )
> , RCTE_Managers AS (
>   SELECT
>     manager as base_manager
>   , 1 as depth
>   , employee
>   , manager as direct_manager
>   FROM employees
>   WHERE manager IS NOT NULL
>   
>   UNION ALL
>   
>   SELECT
>     cte.base_manager
>   , cte.depth + 1
>   , emp.employee
>   , emp.manager
>   FROM RCTE_Managers cte
>   JOIN employees emp
>     ON emp.manager = cte.employee
> )
> SELECT 
>   emp.employee
> , COUNT(DISTINCT mgr.employee) AS subordinates
> FROM CTE_Employees emp
> LEFT JOIN RCTE_Managers mgr 
>   ON mgr.base_manager = emp.employee
> GROUP BY emp.employee
> ORDER BY COUNT(mgr.employee) DESC, emp.employee;
> ```

> | employee | subordinates |
> | --- | --- |
> | Robert | 4 |
> | Julian | 2 |
> | Lucy | 1 |
> | John | 0 |
> | Sophie | 0 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e57e378e4b8f002ff97e759e441ca61)*

Comment: All employees could be added as managers of NULL in the anchor of the recursion..`where manager is not null union all select employee as base_manager, 1, null as employee … union all …rcte..`

Comment: @LukStorms This worked wonders, thanks! If you don't mind, could you briefly explain how this recursion works to get the counts? It seems setting the anchor to get all employees that do report to somebody coupled with the left join was the key, but I don't see it that clearly.

Comment: [Here's an old attempt of mine to explain recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55947847/4003419). And try to `select *` from the CTE's without the group by. And realise that a COUNT of a column doesn't count the NULL's

Comment: Also, lookup what a [LEFT JOIN](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-left-join/) does.